# TOR browsers for iPad

Tags: ios

I'd like to download a TOR browser for my IPad.  I don't see an option on the project website and I see several in the App Store.  I want to download a reputable one where I don't download a security risk. Any thoughts on reputable choices?

Comment: There are no current recommendations. They've all got flaws and have documented to be leaky in the past. (e.g. fetching stuff from a tor session over a non-tor connection)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Onion Browser; they are open source and pretty well reviewed on the iTunes stores. [Onion Browser Github](https://github.com/mtigas/iOS-OnionBrowser)

Comment: https://github.com/mtigas/iOS-OnionBrowser/issues/63 you can use it but don't use it under the belief it provides any strong protections. http://xordern.net/ip-leakage-of-mobile-tor-browsers.html see my original comment, they all have flaws.